# To graph a function

Tags: trigonometry

To graph $$2\sin^2 x -4\sin x - 9.$$  How do I graph this? I wanted to make a rough sketch without using calculator.

Thanks

Comment: Without limits, you'll need _lots_ of paper. But that would be repetitive, it's periodic, so I'd suggest to restrict it to the interval $[0,2\,\pi]$.

Comment: @ProfessorVector i can find values at 0, pi/2, pi ,2pi. But how do i know how to join these dots

Comment: @ProfessorVector How do i do this using limits?

Comment: Find the derivative, then you should know how to join the points.

Comment: At first I would suggest searching for a formula to simplify $\sin^2(x)$, because this can actually be written nicely in terms of $\sin$ and $\cos$ without exponents.

Comment: After plotting it with the computer, I think the over all shape is not *very easy* to guess.

Comment: You can also substitute $u = \sin(x)$ to solve $2u^2 - 4u -9 = 0$ in order to find the roots.

Comment: @Mathias Can you elaborate using derivatives

Comment: 1. Find the derivative of this function which is $2\sin(x)\cos(x)-4\cos(x)$.
2. Test $x = 0, \pi/2, \pi, 3\pi/2, 2\pi$. If the derivative at x is positive, that means that your graph has positive slope at x, same if it is negative. If the derivative would happen to be zero, you'd have a local minimum or maximum.
With this information you should be able to roughly sketch your graph.

Answer (score -1):

plot $\big(0,-9\big)\big(\dfrac{\pi}2,-11\big)\big(-\dfrac{\pi}2,-3\big)$ and feature of $\sin x$ shows following image.[image]